# Wordpress Shared Taxonomy (Query specific post type from taxonomy)

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have custom shared taxonomy named: Related People. This taxonomy refers to few post types, for example: Publications and Specialisations.

So, in my taxonomy I have term, for example: Johnny Bravo. And Johnny Bravo has few Publications and few Specialisations. How can I query only Specialisations connected to Johnny Bravo term in that shared taxonomy?

Comment: Do you know where to find the right section of the wordpress documentation?

Comment: Yes, but the point is I'm looking here for explanation how to use it. I'm not a very pro so here I can name all dependencies that fits my problem, and then, with help I will create my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Wp_Query:

```
$specialisations = new Wp_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'Specialisations',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'Related People',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => 'Johnny Bravo'
        )
    )
));
```

This should fetch all "Specialisations" that have custom taxonomy "Related People" with value "Johnny Bravo". You can see more examples and parameters at [Wp_Query codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Comment: I will try this and let you know if it works. But I have another question: let's say, Johnny Bravo have only Specialisations, and dont have Publications. Can I check this somehow in template? For example I want to create a filter based on this term. So in my archive-publications.php and in archive-specialisations.php I want to get_terms() from taxonomy Related People, but check, if Johnny Bravo have Specialisations or Publications. So based on my example, I want to show this term in Specialisations, but dont show in Publications template. Is this possible?